# Replace a variable, by a reference to an element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

I have a class that works properly and uses an integer as a flags variable (bitwise operations):

```
class foo{
   uint32_t flags;
   ...
};
```

I want to extend this flags to a much higher size, for example 512. But I want to keep the old code working agnostic to the new size.

I tried this but does not work:

```
class foo{
   uint32_t flags_ext[16];
   uint32_t& flags = flags_ext[0];
   ...
};
```

Gives me bunch of problems when doing asignment, etc. Aditionally warns me of a possible double deletion of memory.

Any way to make the code behave but that uint32_t be a part of an array?

Comment: How would you know which part of the array needs to get updated?

Comment: "Foo" will only operate on the first index [0], agnostic to the fact that the variable is part of the array.

Comment: another option might be to keep `flags` and go `uint32_t extra_flags[15];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

implement proper default, copy constructor and assignment operator and you should be good to go:

```
class foo{
   uint32_t flags_ext[16];
   uint32_t& flags;

   foo():
       flags( flags_ext[0] )
   {}

   // copy c'tor takes care _not_ to copy the reference member
   foo( const foo& other ):
       flags( flags_ext[0] )
   { ::memcpy(flags_ext, other.flags_ext, sizeof(flags_ext)); }

   const foo& operator=(const foo& other) {
      if( this==&other )
          return *this;
      // do _not_ copy the 'flags' member!
      ::memcpy(flags_ext, other.flags_ext, sizeof(flags_ext));
      return *this;
   }
};
```

Comment: That should work, but I still have problems, since inside the class pointer operations are used and gives me a `cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted`. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Well, you didn't mention _that_ ;-) (other than now). But that too should be fixable, I think?

Comment: This works but it is ugly because we lose "rule of zero" for the class. (although I don't have a better idea right now)

Comment: I have had to resort to this dirty trick. As long as you hide it well, and don't overuse this technique (you should _never_ have _references_ as data members!), it might be a forgivable pragmatic solution to provide backwards compatibility in a large-ish codebase.